# Speeding up OpenCV on ARM?

Tags: ros, opencv, vision-opencv, gumstix

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm working with OpenCV on a Gumstix, and it is incredibly slow.  For instance, running the "GoodFeaturesToTrack" function in a node runs at 1.5Hz, and requires 85% processor utilization on a Gumstix Overo Tide.  I used a standard download and compile of the ROS vision_opencv package to get these results.  Any ideas on how to optimize?  It seems that even a lowly 700MHz processor should be a bit faster than what I'm getting.

Thanks!

---

**Update**

I'm looking into Ash Charles' suggestion to add a flag to use the neon coprocessor.  I'm not quite sure how to do this.  I'm assuming that I make a change to my opencv2 makefile, but would appreciate some direction on that.

---

**Update #2**

I'm working on implementing RahulP's suggestion.  So, in the vision_opencv package, I added a flag to CMakeLists.txt, which now looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)

set(ROSPACK_MAKEDIST true)
set(EXTRA_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "${EXTRA_C_FLAGS_RELEASE} -O2 -mfpu=neon")
   
rosbuild_make_distribution(1.4.3)
```

Then, I ran `rosmake vision_opencv` which was successful.  However, running the code showed no improvement whatsoever in execution speed (as measured by running rostopic hz /output).

Did I skip a step here?  Or do I need to be looking into profiling?  I tried using oprofile, but didn't really get anywhere productive.  If you have any suggestions, they would be much appreciated.

---

**Potential Update/Question**

If I were to go to my OpenCV directory, and type in:

```
./configure -mfpu=neon
```

followed by running rosmake, would that have the desired effect?

---

**Update**

I've uploaded all of my code to [Github.](http://https://github.com/bradleypowers/laser)  The main program that I'd like to optimize is in nodes/find_laser_filtered.py.  Obviously, one easy thing to do is to get rid of filtering lines by angle, that was mostly for debugging purposes on the desktop.

If you get an opportunity to take a look, please suggest any ideas for improvement you may have.  I'd really like to get this running at 15+ Hz, and I'm currently at about 2 Hz...

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10273/speeding-up-opencv-on-arm?/) by [Bradley Powers](https://answers.ros.org/users/501/bradley-powers/) on ROS Answers with karma: 422 on 2011-06-15

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-10-25**:
@Bradley, @Ash, the last "update" and Ash's comment should be put in an answer so that others trying to solve the same problem will know where to look without reading the entire comment history. I'd suggest cleaning up the question as well.

**Comment by [Ash Charles](https://answers.ros.org/users/679/ash-charles/) on 2011-10-25**:
I looked at the recommended gcc flags for VFP and Neon support.  I believe "-march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a8 -mfpu=neon -O3" would be best.  '-O3' should do some auto-vectorizing. Unfortunately, this will still be soft float (-mfloat-abi-softfp) as hard float is an ongoing challenge.

**Comment by [Bradley Powers](https://answers.ros.org/users/501/bradley-powers/) on 2011-10-24**:
I had trouble with oprofile itself.  I'll take a look at sysprof tomorrow and post results.

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-10-24**:
What is meant by "didn't really get anywhere productive"? Do you mean that you couldn't find a bottle neck, or that you had trouble with oprofile itself? If it's the latter I'd suggest sysprof which is much easier to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I agree this seems slow so two thoughts crossed my mind.

1. Check what is actually using all the processor time with something like oprofile. The processor shouldn't be doing tons of math or swapping of buffers but knowing what this is a first step.
2. Hard-float capabilities are provided by the Neon and vfp extensions.  IIRC, CMake should pick up flags from the environment so try adding '-mfpu=neon' to CXXFLAGS prior to recompiling.

The DSP onboard provides powerful capabilities when used with gstreamer---this may also give some benefit.

---

Originally posted by [Ash Charles](https://answers.ros.org/users/679/ash-charles/) with karma: 81 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-06-17**:
See http://elinux.org/BeagleBoard/GSoC/2010_Projects/OpenCV for a GSoC project on using the DSP and OpenCV together.

**Comment by [Bradley Powers](https://answers.ros.org/users/501/bradley-powers/) on 2011-06-17**:
Interesting, I'll look into this.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The easiest way to do this is to trick the build setup by doing the modifaction mentioned below in the file CMakeLists.txt.

```
# Other optimizations 
if(USE_O2)

    set(EXTRA_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "${EXTRA_C_FLAGS_RELEASE} -O2 -mfpu=neon")

endif()
```

Dont forget to turn ON the USE_O2 options while configuring your build. This modifcation only applies to earlier versions of OpenCV. The latest version of OpenCV (version 2.3.1) supports building OpenCV with NEON enabled directly via CMake

---

Originally posted by [RahulP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1171/rahulp/) with karma: 11 on 2011-10-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bradley Powers](https://answers.ros.org/users/501/bradley-powers/) on 2011-10-24**:
So, I added set(EXTRA_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "${EXTRA_C_FLAGS_RELEASE} -O2 -mfpu=neon") to my CMakeLists.txt, and then ran rosmake vision_opencv.  I didn't use the if statement, as I'm compiling this specifically for the ARM.  I'm not super familiar with this whole system, is that the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have done lot of optimization work on OpenCV on ARM and not ARM. Main gains I got us just looking into OpenCV code and just optimizing it for my particular use. For example often there is a some sort of "if ( 8 bit color) or ( 16 bit color)" and I make millions of calls to this function. Of course I never use randomly different color depths, so I just can remove this "if". Doing this in as many places possible usually leads with huge boost from some point as compiler realize some way to optimize it after. Mostly with inlining, comptuting constants while compiling etc. All kind of magic with GCC flags usually provides result in range of 1% up to 5%, no more. Of course when -O2 at least in place.
So just cut and paste parts of OpenCV you use into own code and then strip them down as much you can. Do not worry too much, usually those algorithms are just few hundred lines.

---

Originally posted by [tonuonu](https://answers.ros.org/users/1122/tonuonu/) with karma: 21 on 2011-11-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bradley Powers](https://answers.ros.org/users/501/bradley-powers/) on 2011-11-14**:
Interesting.  So, at the moment, my code uses very little actual OpenCV code.  cv_bridge, CvtColor, CreateMemStorage, Smooth, Canny, Houghlines2, and Line.  I'm also using the Python bindings, and I'm not sure how bad that is in terms of slowdowns.